# How to extract the ID token after google authentication if I use the scope openid in java?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I made a small spring boot project and I need the id token. When I try to open an endpoint what requires google login I can login and then see the result of the endpoint calling. My question is that how to get the ID token? Where it can be found? How to extract it?

I send the `openid` scope but no idea where is the id token can be found to put the name/email/whatever on the front page if I want to:

```
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri          = https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me

security.oauth2.client.client-id                = clientid
security.oauth2.client.client-secret            = clientsecret
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri   = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri         = https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
security.oauth2.client.scope                    = openid email profile
```

Thanks in advance.